# Object.keys returns empty array when used in parent class' constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to be able to assign the properties to instances of my object if any of the keys match the ones defined as a public instance field.

This works fine when I have the constructor containing this logic within the same class declaration but if this logic is inherited from the parent class it stops working.

Example Code:

```js
class SuperClass {
  constructor(data = {}) {
    Object.keys(this).forEach(key => { this[key] = data[key] });
  }
}

class InheritingClass extends SuperClass {
  foo;
}

class NonInheritingClass {
  // same as above in SuperClass
  constructor(data = {}) {
    Object.keys(this).forEach(key => { this[key] = data[key] });
  }

  foo;
}

const parameters = { foo: "bar" };
const nonWorkingInstance = new InheritingClass(parameters);
const workingInstance = new NonInheritingClass(parameters);

console.log(nonWorkingInstance.foo);
// undefined
console.log(workingInstance.foo);
// "bar"
```

Is there any way to have it work so I can keep the `constructor` logic in the parent class (`SuperClass`)?

Comment: No, you'll have to look for another solution, like defining & calling a non-constructor method in the super class. The order of execution is `super()`, then initialisation of fields, then constructor.

Comment: The name "public class field" is confusing. It's actually an instance field, not accessible from the class, and the parent constructor doesn't know anything about it.

Comment: You're right, updated to public instance field

Comment: Nah, "public class field" is the proper, official term; the question was fine. I just was complaining that it's a misleading term. Like trincot says, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is what this compiles down to, especially the order and where setting this property `foo;` is added: AFTER the super-call and BEFORE anything else in the own constructor.

```js
class SuperClass {
  constructor(data = {}) {
    console.log(this, this.constructor);

    Object.keys(this).forEach(key => {
      this[key] = data[key]
    });
  }
}

class InheritingClass extends SuperClass {
  constructor(data = {}) {
    super(data);

    this.foo = void 0;  // <--- here, AFTER the super() call
  }
}

class NonInheritingClass {
  // same as above in SuperClass
  constructor(data = {}) {
    this.foo = void 0;  // <-- but BEFORE any other code in the own constructor.

    console.log(this);

    Object.keys(this).forEach(key => {
      this[key] = data[key]
    });
  }
}
```

And since the `super()` call has to be the first thing in a derived constructor you have no chance to define the property in a way that.

imo the best solution would be to move the *assign-values* logic into an method and call it explicitely AFTER all constructors have run:

```js
class SuperClass {
  assign(data = {}) {
    Object.keys(this).forEach(key => { this[key] = data[key] });
    return this;
  }
}

class InheritingClass extends SuperClass {
  foo;
}

const parameters = { foo: "bar" };
const nonWorkingInstance = new InheritingClass().assign(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version, 2 problems .
First: you need to call super in the child class to pass the parameters to the parent construction before the child constructor.
Second: this in Object is referring to the parent Object so foo will be defined only in the Parent, after removing this, it is working fine!

```js
class SuperClass {
    constructor(data = {}) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
            this[key] = data[key];
        });
    }
}

class InheritingClass extends SuperClass {
    constructor(data) {
        super(data);
    }
}

class NonInheritingClass {
    // same as above in SuperClass
    constructor(data = {}) {
        Object.keys(this).forEach((key) => {
            this[key] = data[key];
        });
    }

    foo;
}

const parameters = { foo: 'bar' };
const nonWorkingInstance = new InheritingClass(parameters);
const workingInstance = new NonInheritingClass(parameters);

console.log(nonWorkingInstance.foo);
// undefined
console.log(workingInstance.foo);
// "bar"
```

Answer (score -1):

This should fix it.
Parent class only uses its own and its Parent class public/protected variables but not its child variables.

```
class SuperClass {
    constructor(data = {}) {
      Object.keys(this).forEach(key => { this[key] = data[key] });
    }

    foo;
}

class InheritingClass extends SuperClass {}

const parameters = { foo: "bar" };
const nonWorkingInstance = new InheritingClass(parameters);
console.log(nonWorkingInstance.foo);
```